# SectionProperties.AddSection not working properly - bug?

Tags: vsto, powerpoint

I've just came across a buggy behaviour of SectionProperties.AddSection. Let's say I have four sections already created:

```
1. Default
2. Overview
3. Details
4. Conclusions
```

And now I call a code:

```
Presentation.SectionProperties.AddSection(3, "Overview details");
```

According to the documentation: [SectionProperties.AddSection Method (PowerPoint)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff746122.aspx) **Overview Details** section should be created before Details section.

But instead of getting

```
1. Default
2. Overview
3. Overview Details
4. Details
5. Conclusions
```

I end up with:

```
1. Default
2. Overview details
3. Overview
4. Details
5. Conclusions
```

Is it a common issue? I did some testing and it seems that inserting new sections works properly only when new section is inserted at the beginning or end.

Thanks,
Paweł

Comment: I'm getting even odder behavior.  In a presentation with one slide in sectino 3 and no slides in the previous two sections, adding a new section results in the section being added at the beginning of the presentation, ie, index 1, regardless of the index I specify, unless it's 4 (ie, one more than the number of existing sections, in which case it's added at the end of the presentation).  It seems that you need at least one slide prior to and after the existing section you want to insert the new section ahead of, if you want it to work.  Buggy indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saw your post on MS Answers as well and in between, had a bit more time to play with this. It's indeed buggy, but there's a workaround.  The problem occurs when there are no slides in some sections; so we'll add slides to any sections that don't have them, add the section as needed, then delete the just-added "dummy" slides.

```
Sub TestAddSection()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim oSl As Slide

    ' Add a dummy slide to each empty section and tag it
    For x = 1 To ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Count
        Debug.Print ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Name(x)
        If ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.SlidesCount(x) = 0 Then
          ' activepresentation.SectionProperties.
          Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(1, ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1))
          oSl.Tags.Add "DUMMY", "YES"
          oSl.MoveToSectionStart (x)
        End If
    Next

    ' add new section
    ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.AddSection 3, "NEW GUY"

    ' And delete the dummy slides
    With ActivePresentation
        For x = .Slides.Count To 1 Step -1
            If .Slides(x).Tags("DUMMY") = "YES" Then
                .Slides(x).Delete
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm adding the slides at index 1 then moving them to the start of the section where they're needed.  Perhaps there's a way to add them directly to the section, but I couldn't find it.